# cakephp logout redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a cakephp app that when I logout it add's admin/login ti the url of the logging in screen. Then when I log  in again it says missing controler. I already have a redirect to the Auth logout. If I change that will it still logout?

**Original login url:**

mydomain.com/res/admin

**Url after logout**

mydomain.com/res/admin/users/login

**After I log in to admin:**

mydomain.com/res/admin/admin/login

user controller:

```
function admin_logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Comment: From what I understand you set the custom auth settings in a controller with the beforeFilter(). I have   $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('admin_login','admin_logout');
Is there other settings?

Comment: Please provide the relevant configuration of the Auth component, and your routes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by putting a logout redirect in the beforefilter.

Answer (score 1):

In AppController you can do something like this

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'login'),//redirect url
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
```

);

and in UserController

```
public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```

}

this worked for me.